# Need to show the same value once using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

```
<root>
  <dql1>    
    <row>
      <abcd> Prod 1 </abcd>
      <td_formulation_name> 123 </td_formulation_name>
    </row>  
    <row>
      <abcd> Prod 2 </abcd>
      <td_formulation_name> 123 </td_formulation_name>
    </row>
   </dql1> 
</root>
```

I want to show the output as :-

- Prod 1
- Prod 2
- 123

How is it possible through XSLT ?  Can any one please help ?

Comment: As your tags suggest, this is a grouping problem.  What have you tried so far, and what version of XSLT do you have available?  If you have 2.0 then look up `for-each-group`, if you only have 1.0 then look up "Muenchian grouping".

Answer (score 0):

You can just access them using below xslt. Though not very sure if you need this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="root/dql1/row/abcd"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="root/dql1/row[2]/abcd"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="root/dql1/row/td_formulation_name"/> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you do not know the index or if it is dynamic you can do

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/dql1/row">
    <xsl:value-of select="abcd" />
    <xsl:value-of select="td_formulation_name" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hi A Paul,Thanks for your help. But in my case I am not sure abou6t the row count. It is dynamic. So I will not be able to use the Index as you shown? I sthere any other way ?

Comment: Its simple, you can just loop on the row. Check my edit in above post